# SQL Server Connection with Apache Airflow

Tags: sql-server, airflow

I have installed Docker's desktop and VS code for Apache airflow. Now I am trying to create connections with PostgreSQL and SQL Server at Airflow Admin UI. At the connection type drop down I am able to see PostgreSQL connection type and can successfully create the connection. However, I am unable to see SQL Server connection. Can anyone guide me in this?

[image]

Comment: Did you install the Microsoft SQL Server provider and its pymssql dependency?

Comment: On VS code terminal I have executed "pip install apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql" only.

Comment: The provider needs to be installed inside the Airflow containers themselves. If you were starting from the demo [https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.8.0/docker-compose.yaml](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.8.0/docker-compose.yaml), for example, then `pip install apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql` needs to be executed inside each of the `webserver`, `worker` and `scheduler` containers so that the required components are available in each of the environments that need them.